# Android RSA encryption and Python decryption

Tags: java, android, python, encryption, pycrypto

I'm trying to make an Android app which logs a user into a Django-based server. I'm trying to increase the security by encrypting the username and password, but for some reason it's not decrypting properly on the server-side.

I suspect it has to do with the Java encryption and PyCrypto encryption differing slightly and causing compatibility issues, but I'm too green to really know what's wrong.

Here's the encryption code on the app (followed [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/rsa-string-encryption-security) tutorial):

```
public String encrypt_rsa(String original) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.public_key);
    byte[] encodedKey = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(encodedKey);
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pkPublic = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    Cipher pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    pkCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pkPublic);
    byte[] encryptedInByte = pkCipher.doFinal(original.getBytes());
    String encryptedInString = new String(Base64Coder.encode(encryptedInByte));
    is.close();

    return encryptedInString;
}
```

And here's my Python Code

```
from Cryto.PublicKey import RSA

def decrypt(encoded_text):

    f = open("/path_to_file/private_key.pem", 'r')
    priv_key = RSA.importKey(f)

    encrypted_text = base64.b64decode(encoded_text)

    plain_text = priv_key.decrypt(encrypted_text)

    return plain_text
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: It is not decrypting properly is not a very helpful error description...

Answer (score 1):

The Java code is using PKCS#1 v1.5 RSA encryption, which is a seriously broken and unsecure protocol.

Having said that, the decryption is done in Python with the appropriate module:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5

priv_key = RSA.importKey(f)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(priv_key)
plain_text = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text)
```

More more information, see [the module documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html).